# If a plane's impeded magic trait requires a Spellcraft check to cast a spell, can a character without ranks in Spellcraft cast that spell?

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e, planes, spellcasting

This is a follow-up to this question: [Does using a magic item that produces a spell effect on a plane with the impeded magic trait require a Spellcraft check?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/157364/magic-items-that-produce-impeded-magic-spell-effects)

---

The SRD's description of the [Impeded Magic](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/planes.htm#impededMagic) [magic trait](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/planes.htm#magicTraits) for a plane says:

> Particular spells and spell-like abilities are more difficult to cast on planes with this trait, often because the nature of the plane interferes with the spell.
>
> To cast an impeded spell, the caster must make a Spellcraft check (DC 20 + the level of the spell). If the check fails, the spell does not function but is still lost as a prepared spell or spell slot. If the check succeeds, the spell functions normally.

Can an impeded spell or spell-like ability can be cast/produced on a plane which impedes that type of magic if the character doesn't possess any ranks in Spellcraft? (Spellcraft is a trained-only skill.) If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have any ranks in Spellcraft and lack an ability that allows you to make skill checks untrained, you cannot attempt Spellcraft checks.

> ### Untrained
>
> This entry indicates what a character without at least 1 rank in the skill can do with it. If this entry doesn’t appear, it means that the skill functions normally for untrained characters (if it can be used untrained) or that an untrained character can’t attempt checks with this skill (for skills that are designated as “Trained Only”).

Spellcraft has no Untrained section.

To cast an impeded spell, you must make a Spellcraft check.  You can't, so you can't cast an impeded spell.  At all.  You don't lose a spell slot, because you don't fail the check. You don't have the spell happen, because you don't succeed. You essentially can't even try to cast the spell.

Comment: This is my understanding also, it's always good to a get a second opinion.